# compile Clojure *.clj into *.class, some functions are not generated

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am following the instructions from [here](http://dynamic-thinking.blogspot.gr/2009/06/clojure-first-steps-into-compilation.html) and am trying to generate a Java class from **clj** sources by invoking **lein jar**.

However, when I edited the code a little to add a test function of my own:

```
(ns some.Example
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [greetee]
  (println (str "Hello " greetee "!")))

(defn -foo []
  "foo bar")
```

.. and then proceeded to generate a Java class file with **lein jar** (I append the project.clj at the end of the post) I found that the generated **jar** contains the methods as inner classes:

```
$ jar tvf example-1.0.0.jar 
    76 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  1225 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 META-INF/maven/some/example/pom.xml
    87 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 META-INF/maven/some/example/pom.properties
  2697 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 some/Example__init.class
  1499 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 some/Example$loading__4784__auto__.class
  1035 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 some/Example$_main.class
   565 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 some/Example$_foo.class
  1771 Sun Feb 17 20:56:24 EET 2013 some/Example.class
   162 Sun Feb 17 18:03:12 EET 2013 project.clj
   129 Sun Feb 17 19:23:54 EET 2013 some/Example.clj
```

and that the **some.Example** class contains only the **main** method but not the **foo**:

```
$ javap some.Example
public class some.Example {
  public static {};
  public some.Example();
  public java.lang.Object clone();
  public int hashCode();
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

So the question is: how can we specify a **clj** Clojure file that generates a Java class with a number of static and instance methods with the aim of calling these methods from Java code?

### project.clj used for the *lein jar* operation

```
(defproject some/example "1.0.0"
  :description "A sample project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
  :aot [some.Example]
  :source-paths ["."]
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the methods that your class is going to have:

```
(ns some.Example
  (:gen-class
     :methods [[foo [] String]]))
```

Note that this declares foo as a non-static method so it also needs to take a `this` parameter:

```
(defn -foo [this]
  "foo bar")
```

If you want the method to be static, you need to attach some metadata:

```
(ns some.Example
      (:gen-class
         :methods [#^{:static true}[bar [] int]]))
(defn -bar []
  3)
```

Try reading [this](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html), it gets somewhat faster to the point.